# Parser for the Mathematica syntax?

Tags: c#, parsing, wolfram-mathematica

Is there a built parser that I can use from C# that can parse mathematica expressions?

I know that I can use the Kernel itself to parse an expression, and use .NET/Link to retrieve the tree structure... But I'm looking for something that doesnt rely on the Kernel.

Comment: Perhaps someone wrote a parser in ANTLR?

Comment: There is a Mathematica parser out there (at least a description is linked at http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~fateman/) but it's written in Common Lisp, which, as far as I know doesn't have a CLR/.NET implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My [matheclipse-parser module](https://github.com/axkr/symja-parser) implements a parser in Java which can parse a big subset of mathematica expressions. See the readme.md page for usage. Maybe you can port the parser to C#?

Answer (score 1):

The mathematica grammar isn't well documented, true.  But AFAIK, it is
LALR(1) and likely LL(1); the bracketed /tagged syntax from gives the parser complete clues
about what to expect next, just like LISP and XML.

The [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit) does have a Mathematica grammar that has been used for real tasks.
This includes MMa programs as well as pure expression forms.

That probably doesn't help you, since you want one in C#.

If you have access to the Kernal, I'd stick to that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think such a thing exists already (I'd love to know about it).  But it may be useful that within Mathematica you can apply the function `FullForm` to any expression and get something very easy to parse, kind of like an s-expression in Lisp.  For example,

```
FullForm[a+b*c]
```

yields

```
Plus[a, Times[b,c]]
```

That's the underlying representation of all Mathematica expressions and should be straightforward to parse.

Comment: Yes.. but for that I need the Kernel. Anyways... I think you are right. Such parser doesn't seem to exist. Part of the problem is that there is no published grammar for the language. I've also heard that the language cannot be parsed with a LALR parser.