# Implementation of differentiation in C#

Tags: c#, math

I have the following differentiation, I need to implement it in C#:

```
W(t)=d/dt(log(A(t)))
```

Where `A(t)` is a array of double data.

How can I obtain the resulting `W(t)` array from the derivative above?

Thanks

edit:

```
public double[,] derivative()
{
    dvdt = new double[envelope.GetLength(0), envelope.GetLength(1)];
    int h = 1;

    for (int j = 0; j < envelope.GetLength(0); j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < envelope.GetLength(1)-1 ; i++)
        {
            dvdt[j, i] = (envelope[j, i + h] - envelope[j, i]) / (h);
        }
    }
    return dvdt;
}
```

I found this library http://autodiff.codeplex.com/ but i cant understand how the sample code is working and how i can apply it to my problem eh

Comment: Sounds like a typical homework question :D

Comment: Are we looking for a generic differentiation solver, or just for `log`?

Comment: its not im stuck in my thesis and i cant get a good result.

Comment: Post what you have; it'll be easier for everyone.

Comment: @the communist duck at the moment i need to solve log A(t) but if the generic solver will work ill give that a shot

Comment: A generic solver, AFAICS, would be exponentially more difficult.

Comment: When you say `A(t)` is an array, do you mean `A` is an array and you're multiplying it by t, or do you mean `A` is a function which, given `t`, will return an array, or something else entirely?

Comment: A(t) is a function but in c# the data of this function is an array

Comment: @Tristan Demanuele, could you post a simple example of how this `A(t)` function is defined in your code? When you say that the data of this function is an array what do you mean?

Comment: @darin dimitrov in the code i posted above A(t) is the envelope[]

Comment: @Tristan: autodiff will tell you what the derivative is of a given expression.

Comment: @Tristan Demanuele: The envelope[] is a constant value at this point, so its `d/dt` will always be zero (because it is not given in relation to `t`). You might as well be finding the derivative of 10.

Answer (score 3):

None of this *directly* addresses your question, but it may help you to get moving again. Getting stuck on trivial items in your thesis can be a royal pain.

Do you have access to Mathematica? [Last I checked they had a .NET wrapper around their core engine called .NET/Link.](http://www.wolfram.com/learningcenter/tutorialcollection/NETLinkUserGuide/NETLinkUserGuide.pdf)

The performance of Mathematica is stellar. Also, it now supports resources such as GPUs and clusters which could provide a huge performance boost if any of your app lends itself to parallelization.

This would let you focus on the rest of your app instead of having to reinvent the wheel. Also, since you could enter your formulas directly in the Mathematica notebook editor, you could take a more generic, data-driven approach from the C# side.

[Here is some typically-impenetrable Wolfram documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/NETLink/tutorial/CallingMathematicaFromNET.html).

[See also this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608380/parser-for-the-mathematica-syntax) about parsing Mathematica in C#.

(I only recommend Mathematica because you mentioned that you may need a solver for more than one formula/equation/etc. Unless *implementing* the solver is a core part of your theses topic, I'd recommend using an off-the-shelf component like this and focusing on your original research.)

Answer (score 1):

To find the derivative of a logarithmic function:

> where y = log<sub>b</sub> u
> dy/dx = log<sub>b</sub>(e) * u*'*/u
> where u*'* = du/dx

http://www.intmath.com/differentiation-transcendental/5-derivative-logarithm.php#derivbases

So in order to answer your question, we would need to know the derivative of `A(t)`. If you don't know what A(t) is ahead of time, then you'll need to come up with some kind of generic solver, or require that the input includes both the function A and its derivative.

```
public double Log10Derivative(Func<double, double> a, 
                              Func<double, double> aPrime, 
                              double t)
{
    return Math.Log10(Math.E) * (aPrime(t) / a(t));
}
```

As far as performing a `log` on an array, I either never learned that or I forgot how.

#### Edit

This should give you an approximation:

```
public double Log10Derivative(Func<double, double> a, 
                              double t)
{
    const double reallySmallNumber = double.Epsilon;
    var aPrimeEst = (a(t) - a(t + reallySmallNumber)) / reallySmallNumber;
    return Math.Log10(Math.E) * (aPrimeEst / a(t));
}
```

Comment: and to find the derivative of A(t) can i use change in y/change in x?

Comment: Yes, it would be a constant `k`.

Comment: @Tristan Demanuele: The question is "how big a change in x?" You can approximate it using a very small change in X, but your answer won't be exact.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you work out the formula for the derivative on your own, and if memory serves `d/dx[log_b x] = [1/(x ln b)] dx`. If `A(t)` is a simple array:

```
double log_b = Math.Log(10); // Assumes Math.Log = ln and b = 10
double dt = 1.0;             // dt is 1 in this case, change if otherwise

double[] W = new double[A.GetLength(0)];
for (int t = 0; t < A.GetLength(0); ++t)
{
    W[t] = dt / (A[t] * log_b);
}
```

Comment: `Math.Log(10)` represents `ln 10`. You want `Math.Log10(t)`, right?

Comment: I'm a bit rusty, but I believe it is `ln b` in the derivative term, or is that not correct?

Comment: `d/dx[log_b x] = log_b(e) x'/x` (http://www.intmath.com/differentiation-transcendental/5-derivative-logarithm.php#derivbases), so if b = 10, you want `Math.Log10(Math.E)`, or `Math.Log(Math.E, 10)`.

Comment: Interesting, I had used (http://people.hofstra.edu/Stefan_Waner/RealWorld/tutorials/unit3_3.html) as a reference, which does it differently. My answer isn't terribly applicable anymore as it appears `A[t]` is actually the result of a function.

Comment: Ha, guess what? `(1/Math.Log(10))` and `Math.Log10(Math.E)` are apparently the same thing. Go figure. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think many of the answers are overthinking this.  `d/dt(log(x))` is just `1/x`, so you just need to calculate the reciprocal for each point in the array `A`.

```
double[] W = Array.ConvertAll<double, double>(A, x => 1.0 / x);
```